# derivative of composition curve

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves, differential, pushforward

a quick question:

Let $(M,g), (N,h) $ be pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, $\gamma:I \rightarrow M$ a curve.

$\gamma^{'}(t_0):= d \gamma \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} |_{t_0}$

Let $F:M \rightarrow M$ be an isometry.

Is it true then, that

$(F \circ \gamma)^{'}(t_0)= d(F \circ \gamma) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t_0} =dF_{\gamma(t_0)} \gamma^{'}= F_{*} \gamma^{'}$

where $F_{*}$ denotes the push-forward.

Comment: $\gamma'$ isn't a pullback, it's a pushforward. Also there's no need for a (pseudo)-Riemannian structure. Pushforward is functorial by the chain rule.

Comment: Hey, if I understand your comment right, you meant the last term? That was a mistake, I corrected it, it wasn't supposed to be a pullback.

Comment: Yes, that was half of what the first sentence was commenting on. The other half of the first sentence was that $\gamma'=\gamma_*\partial_t$, so you can use functoriality of pullbacks (I.e., the chain rule).

Comment: I'm sorry, I still do not completely understand what you mean,  I don't know what you mean by functoriality and why can't I just use the chain rule for $C^{\infty}$ functions?

Comment: Sorry I meant functoriality of push forward. But yeah it's the chain rule.

Comment: Ok, so my computation is right?